# How can I control my Json with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have JSON data and I have two array with `cities` and `countries`.When I clicked my input cities are opening automatically but I want to do this too:

if I cliked my input cities must open (this is okey I did it)

but at the same time if I wrote something for example `denmark` (this is the list of countries) than denmark must seen if is matching.. how can I do that ?

[click to see if you see on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/ZeorJg)

```js
var myJSON = '{ "cities":[ "copenhagen", "london", "hamburg" ], "countries":[ "denmark", "norway", "sweden" ] }';

var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
   var testInput = document.getElementById("test");
    testInput.setAttribute("data-list", myObj.countries)

function showlist() {

}


var comboplete = new Awesomplete('input.dropdown-input', {
 minChars: 0,
});
Awesomplete.$('#test').addEventListener("click", function() {
 if (comboplete.ul.childNodes.length === 0) {
  comboplete.minChars = 0;
  comboplete.evaluate();
 }
 else if (comboplete.ul.hasAttribute('hidden')) {
  comboplete.open();
 }
 else {
  comboplete.close();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>


<input id="test" class="dropdown-input" />
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly do you need? You say `if I cliked my input cities must open (this is okey I did it)`, but when I click the input countries open, not cities.

Comment: hi..when clicked input cities are opening automatically but I have another list `countries` but when I wrote `denmark` or `norway` norway or denmark must seen

Comment: sorry when I clicked only cities must be shown but when I wrote a something if I match two array data must be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I get from your question is that you want entries from both arrays to show when you type anything. To achieve that use `(myObj.cities.concat(myObj.countries))` array instead of `myObj.cities` or `myObj.countries` array alone.

Comment: if I clicked my input only cities must open automatically but if I wrote for example `norway` than norway must showing too

Comment: this method shows entries from both arrays.... i think this is what you want to achieve

Comment: yes but when I clicked only cities must be shown that's exactly what I want